# How to set text in `selectizeInput` which is not in choices from code

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

When I use `options = list(create = TRUE)` in `selectizeInput`, I can manually add a value - see also https://selectize.dev/docs.html and example 3 in https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-examples.html.

How do I add a new value from server code? The example below use a hypothetical `updateSelectizeInput` and expectedly does not work.

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("select", 'Select', 
                 choices = c("anton", "bertha"),
                 options = list(create = TRUE)
                 ),
  actionButton("settext", "Set Text from server")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  # This code does not work, shows the idea
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "select", options = list(value = "Caesar"))  
}

shinyApp(ui, function(input, output, session) {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
library(shiny)

choices <-  c("anton", "bertha")

ui = fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("select", 'Select', 
                 choices = choices,
                 options = list(create = TRUE)
  ),
  actionButton("settext", "Set Text from server")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  # Your update is appending Caesar to the choices
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "select",  choices = c(choices, "Caesar"))  
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Stupefied by your trivial solution, I noted that you answered the question as put, but the question was wrong. Sorry about that. I have revised the original posting.

Comment: Ha. Yes your reputation and question didn't seem to line up.

Comment: I gave the point, because it was the right answer to the wrong question.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("select", 'Select or edit manually',
                 choices = c("anton", "bertha"),
                 options = list(create = TRUE)
                 ),
  verbatimTextOutput("showtext", placeholder = TRUE),
  actionButton("goButton", "Get Text from server")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$showtext = renderPrint({
    input$goButton
    isolate(input$select)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```